# Sort on the last octet of an IP address in a Python list

Tags: python, networking, ip

Here's a bit of a brain boggler (for me at least). I'm utilizing a simple Python script to return a list of "up" hosts using fping. I'm storing each "up" host in a Python list, however the list.sort() won't obviously sort based on the last octet of the IP address stored as a string. I'd like to sort descending .1, .2, .3, etc.

Here's that portion of the code:

```
for addr in os.popen("fping -a -q -g " + subnet):
    addr = addr.rstrip('\n')
    addr_list.append(addr)

addr_list.sort()
for ip in addr_list:
    print ip
```

Comment: Give us an example of your list.

Comment: What does `addr_list` look like before the `.sort()` ?

Comment: `octet`? Did you mean number?

Comment: @Reblochon - each of the four numbers in an IP address is called an octet, because it's represented by 8 bits. For example, in the IP address 192.168.1.101, the first octet is 192, the second octet is 168, etc.

Comment: Why in the world do you *want* to sort by the last octet?  Not saying such a case where it's useful doesn't exist.... its just really weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `addr_list` list looks like this (you haven't specified it in your question):

```
addr_list = [
    '10.11.12.13',
    '1.2.3.4',
    '127.0.0.1',
    '192.168.0.1',
]
```

Split on the `.`'s and use the last item (the last octet) as the key to your sort. Of course, for '127.0.0.1' vs '192.168.0.1' you then probably want to then sort against the 2nd-last octet, and then the 3rd-last octet and then the first.

So using this behaviour as the `key`:

```
>>> list(reversed('10.11.12.13'.split('.')))
['13', '12', '11', '10']
>>> sorted(addr_list, key=lambda ip: list(reversed(ip.split('.'))))
['127.0.0.1', '192.168.0.1', '10.11.12.13', '1.2.3.4']
```

Notice that `13` got listed before `4`. So also ensure that it compares each item as a number and not a string:

```
>>> sorted(addr_list, key=lambda ip: map(int, reversed(ip.split('.'))))
['127.0.0.1', '192.168.0.1', '1.2.3.4', '10.11.12.13']
```

Either assign that to another list or do an in-place sort:

```
>>> addr_list.sort(key=lambda ip: map(int, reversed(ip.split('.'))))
>>> addr_list
['127.0.0.1', '192.168.0.1', '1.2.3.4', '10.11.12.13']
```

Comment: You would need a cast to int in here somewhere, otherwise, they'll sort lexographically instead of numerically, as your final example shows (.13 is before .4, but it should be the reverse).

Answer (score 2):

For just the last octet you can use `rsplit()` in the key:

```
addr_list = [  # Thanks @aneroid
    '10.11.12.13',
    '1.2.3.4',
    '127.0.0.1',
    '192.168.0.1',
]

>>> sorted(addr_list, key=lambda x: int(x.rsplit('.', 1)[1]), reverse=True)
['10.11.12.13', '1.2.3.4', '127.0.0.1', '192.168.0.1']
```

Which is descending - but your example seemed to be ascending:

```
>>> sorted(addr_list, key=lambda x: int(x.rsplit('.', 1)[1]))
['127.0.0.1', '192.168.0.1', '1.2.3.4', '10.11.12.13']
```

But think I would prefer a tuple sort as per @aneroid:

```
>>> sorted(addr_list, key=lambda x: tuple(map(int, reversed(x.split('.')))))
['127.0.0.1', '192.168.0.1', '1.2.3.4', '10.11.12.13']
```

Answer (score 1):

`sort` can take as an argument a function is uses to perform the comparison. The function takes two inputs returns `1` if the first argument is considered greater, `-1` if the second argument is greater, and `0` if they are equal for the purposes of sorting. Here is such a function for your case:

```
def compare_ips(ip1, ip2):
    last_octet1 = int(ip1.split('.')[-1]) # splits the ip and grabs the last octet
    last_octet2 = int(ip2.split('.')[-1]) # splits the ip and grabs the last octet
    if last_octet1 > last_octet2:
        return 1
    if last_octet1 < last_octet2:
        return -1
    return 0
```

You then just supply that as a keyword argument to sort:

```
>>> ips = ['192.168.1.101', '251.39.0.103', '127.0.0.1']
>>> ips.sort(cmp = compare_ips)
>>> ips
['127.0.0.1', '192.168.1.101', '251.39.0.103']
```

Comment: `cmp` is always slower than `key` as it requires "converting" two arguments for each entry in the list.  It's really meant for more complex objects where sorting is less straight forward than can be achieved for a simple conversion to integers.

Comment: @Brian Thanks for the tip! I was not aware of that.

Comment: This one is great as well -- very efficient. Thanks a load.

Comment: I'm glad it helped! No problem!

Answer (score 1):

Sorting by just the last octet is a very bizarre requirement, given that the higher octets usually tell you more about the address (e.g. country/region of origin for publicly routable addresses, subnet for smaller networks).

More generically, this will sort a list of IP addresses by their numeric representation:

```
import socket
ip_list = ['192.168.1.120', '192.168.1.30',  '127.0.0.1']

# numeric sort, leveraging inet_pton to convert valid IPv4 address
# notation to a 'packed' string of 4 bytes, which will then sort correctly.
print sorted(ip_list, key=lambda (x): socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET, x))

# strict string-based sort for comparison
print sorted(ip_list)
```

Or if you'd prefer not to use the socket module for inet_pton:

```
def ip2int(ipstr):
    octets = [int(x) for x in ipstr.split('.')]
    return sum( (o << (8 * 3-i) for i,o in enumerate(octets)) )
sorted(ip_list, key=ip2int)
```

Comment: Agreed -- normally it would be bizarre, but we're just getting a rough idea of hosts on our network. We have around 401 across 32 subnets. It's insanity (last admin was an odd duck).

Answer (score 1):

```
addr_list = [
    '10.11.12.3',
    '1.2.3.4',
    '127.0.0.1',
    '192.168.0.2',
]

# lambda x=192.168.0.2 , ip.split= ['192','168','0','2'][-1] = 2
sorted_ips = sorted(addr_list , key=lambda ip: ip.split('.')[-1])
for ip in sorted_ips:
  print(ip)
```